# Unable to receive interactionCreate Event in DiscordJS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to  implement Slash Commands to my Discord bot but when i try to recieve interaction create events nothing is getting detected with no errors

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
```

The Slash Commands do get added and i can edit their name and stuff but im unable to recieve any interaction create events, it does detect normal messages but doesnot detect any interactionCreate stuff,

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES]
});
);
```

Those are the intents i have provided to the client
**Screenshot**
[image]
Those are the permissions i gave to the bot when i invited it to my server

```
await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientID, devGuildID), {
            body: commandList
        },
    );
    console.log('Successfully registered application commands for development guild');
    rest.get(Routes.applicationCommands(clientID))
       .then(data => console.log(data));
```

When i use this i get "[]" as an output when i console.log

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros since you mentioned it i think i found the issue, i was transferring files between older projects and i updated one of them's discordjs but i was running on the older one with the old discordjs so i think i found the issue